# Wait until subscription data is ready before use it as input

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've been working on a service that gets a list of users that I'll be using as an input for a child component, the problem is that the component loads before users list is done loading, one solution I found is to add `*ngIf` and verify if the array isn't null. However I'd like to found out if this is the best way I can achieve the result I want. This is my code:

```
private getUsersList(): void {
    this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe((response: any[]) => {
        this.usersList = response;
    });
}
```

This is my HTML:

```html
<users-grid 
    *ngIf="usersList"
    [data]="usersList">
</users-grid>`
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having in your `<users-grid>` component when the usersList is null? It would be best to get that component to work properly rather than using the `*ngIf`.

Comment: I was getting undefined for the input I tried to pass to the component.

Answer (score 0):

I can use async pipe

TS:

```
private getUsersList(): void {
    this.usersList = this.usersService.getUsers();    
};
```

HTML:

```html
<users-grid *ngIf="usersList | async; let list"
      [data]="list">
</users-grid>
```

Comment: There is no need for an *ngIf here, just use the async pipe. <users-grid [data]="usersList | async"></users-grid>

Comment: I get no errors if I use this but no data is shown either.